ggplot graph displays wrong colors?
filtered_cAMP_fen <- filtered_cAMP_fen %>%
  mutate(point_color = case_when(
    race_gen == "White_fem" ~ "#000000",
    race_gen == "White_male" ~ "#000000",
    race_gen == "Black_fem" ~ "#FFFFFF",
    race_gen == "Black_male" ~ "#FFFFFF",
    race_gen == "Asian_fem" ~ "#FFFFFF",
    race_gen == "Asian_male" ~ "#FFFFFF"
  ),
  point_border = case_when(
    race_gen == "White_fem" ~ "#000000",
    race_gen == "White_male" ~ "#000000",
    race_gen == "Black_fem" ~ "#FFFFFF",
    race_gen == "Black_male" ~ "#FFFFFF",
    race_gen == "Asian_fem" ~ "#000000",
    race_gen == "Asian_male" ~ "#000000"
  ),
  box_color = case_when(
    race_gen == "White_fem" ~ "#FFFFFF",
    race_gen == "White_male" ~ "#FFFFFF",
    race_gen == "Black_fem" ~ "#000000",
    race_gen == "Black_male" ~ "#000000",
    race_gen == "Asian_fem" ~ "#8B0000",
    race_gen == "Asian_male" ~ "#8B0000"
  ))

# Create the plot
p1 <- filtered_cAMP_fen %>%
  filter(Assay_type == 'cAMP', Cell_Line %in% Plot_Line, exclusion == 'no', Treatment == treatments_for_plot) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(race_gen), y = cAMP_normed_meoh)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = box_color)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = point_color, color = point_border),
             position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.2, dodge.width = 0.75),
             shape = 21, size = 6) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#FFFFFF"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))

print(p1)

and I get this output: The colors are not black, white, and darkred, but red, blue and green? Not sure why the color scheme in the code is messed up
enter image description here
I would like to have the components of the box plot displayed in the colors as indicated in the color scheme. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Try to use scale_fill_manual() for box_color with the colors of your choice.

I tried this before, unfortunately, that didn't work. Then I could not individually change the box_colors, the colors of the dots and the border of the dots

If the variables mapped on color or fill contain literal color codes then try with + scale_color_identity() and scale_fill_identity(). For more help please provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

stefan, thanks a lot, worked, just needed to add scale_color_identity() and scale_full_identity().
